# Google Street View link URL only. Not embed

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I want to clear that I am not trying to embed google street view in my website.

What I am trying to do is to have a URL link to be displayed in my website which will take the users who click the google street view link to Google website and display a street view.

I have Lat/Lng stored in a database. So I am writing a php code to get those to work with URL.

For example:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@38.214969,-122.1065172,10z
```

It works with map display. I can click the url and go to Google Maps and its displayed.

But I want a link to work with streetview aswell and that will take them directly to street view of that lat/lng.

Thank You.

Comment: Go to Google streetview for a latitude and longitude and look at the url, then try to see how that link differs from what you're generating

Comment: But it has other additional details such as: data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s7Q0znx5n579p6tTwAf1Hwg!2e0. Not sure how to replicate it or what it means.

Comment: Take that link, put in your latitude and longitude in place of the ones that are there, if it works you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a static street view image, you can use the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/).

Sample usage:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10
```

Just put your lat/lng value for `location` parameter.

---

If you want to use interactive street view, you have to use [Javascript Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview), here is a sample usage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

You just set the lat/lng in `new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);`
then call the `new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama()` function.